# Check if running inside a PostgreSQL extension setup/upgrade script

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to check whether the current context is during `CREATE EXTENSION` or `ALTER EXTENSION … UPDATE`?

I'm switching over some of my schemas that I managed with my home-brewed PostgreSQL migration framework to be based on extensions instead. In my migration framework, I had various way to see if I was running within a migration, and I would like to see something similar during extension installation/upgrade.

Maybe I must throw and catch an exception and inspect the stack? I hope not…

**Context [added Nov. 21, '22]:** I would like to create an event trigger that ignores events that are part of extension installation and upgrade. To be honest, I don't *really* need this. (I realized that, within my use case, extension installation is handled from *within* migrations anyway.) But, as a theoretical exercise, I still would like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Finding out if and which extension is being installed**

All one has to do to find out if an extension is currently being installed is to create any type of object that would normally become tracked as part of the extension (i.e., any object type that can be appropriated or disowned via [`ALTER EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterextension.html).), and then check (via the [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html) catalog) if that object now depends on an extension (and which extension that is).

The object being tested for belonging to an extension may even be a temporary object:

```sql
create temporary table test_object (col int)
    on commit drop;

select
    pg_extension.extname
from
    pg_catalog.pg_depend
inner join
    pg_catalog.pg_extension
    on pg_extension.oid = pg_depend.refobjid
where
    pg_depend.classid = 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass
    and pg_depend.objid = 'test_object'::regclass
    and pg_depend.refclassid = 'pg_catalog.pg_extension'::regclass
;
```

The above `SELECT` will return `NULL` if this code is run outside of a `CREATE EXTENSION`/`ALTER EXTENSION` context. Otherwise, it will return the name of the extension that is in the process of being installed. (If an extension is being installed due to a dependent extension being installed `WITH CASCADE`, the extension name returned will be the name of the *dependency*, *not* the dependent.)

Of course, normally there would scarcely be a reason to create a dummy object, since the point of many extension set up and upgrade scripts is to *create* objects anyway.

**2. Finding out if the current event trigger fires in the context of an extension script**

I could have just turned to the event trigger documentation for the answer: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html

One of the columns in the `record` set that [`pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-DDL-COMMAND-END-FUNCTIONS) returns is: `in_extension`, which is “[t]rue if the command is part of an extension script”.

Answer (score 2):

Extension scripts have a magic token, `@extschema@`, that gets replaced with the target schema name. You can check if the replacement occurs. I'm not sure it can be in a string literal and still get replaced; its designed to be used in an identifier. Details in the [PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/extend-extensions.html).

As extension scripts have to live in a special place and only get called with `CREATE EXTENSION` / `ALTER EXTENSION UPDATE` and can have protection against being included via `psql` you can be fairly certain about how your code got called. You could put a wrapper on your code that passes a source identifier to an inner function through an argument.

Comment: I like your idea, which I hadn't thought of myself.

However, it doesn't solve my precise problem: I want to create an event trigger that ignores events that take place during `CREATE EXTENSION` and `ALTER EXTENSION … UPDATE`. I will update my question with that bit of context.

Comment: I have edited my answer to contain a better, more universal solution to my problem.